# Gradient in tableViewController is not filling the complete background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I do to set the gradient in my ViewHelper class:

```
class func BackGroundColorTableView(vc: UITableViewController, view:UIView) {

    let startColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.82, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
    let endColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.26, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0)
    let gradientBackgroundColors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

   gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]
    gradientLayer.frame = vc.tableView.bounds

   let backgroundView = UIView(frame: vc.tableView.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    vc.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Then I call my function;

```
 ViewHelper.BackGroundColorTableView(vc: self, view: self.view)
 tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

and the delegate;

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

The problem is, that there is a gap at the bottom, not showing the gradient: see the picture
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSkCi.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: could you please post also your view / tableview / tableviewcell layout constraints?

Comment: BackGroundColorTableView has one argument: sender but you call it with two arguments: vc and view so you use other func or this is mistake?

Comment: @Mateusz, sorry. i`ve checked it, now everything is equally

Comment: @Jez - where are you calling `ViewHelper.BackGroundColorTableView()`? In `viewDidLoad()`? If so, the frame is probably not fully set yet - and you will have an issue when the table view frame changes (such as on rotate).

Comment: @ DonMag . Yeah, in viewDidLoad().  At what place i have call this function? It happens even json is empty.

Comment: @Jez - to confirm something... set `backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red`. If the missing part of the gradient ends up being red, then the issue is with the layer not being sized correctly. Should be easy to fix, if you confirm that to be the problem...

Comment: @ DonMag   , yeah it is red

Comment: @Jez continue to add the layer in `viewDidLoad` but update its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @beyowulf , how to get a part of code with frame? When i call, i recieve all function BackGroundColorTableView()